# Why can't I navigate to the next screen by tapping the button?

Tags: flutter, rest, dart

This is the button that captures a recovery code received through gmail.

```
 onPressed: () async {

                  bool? resp = _recoverKey.currentState?.validate();
                    if (resp!) {
                      setState(() {});
          
                      isLoading = true;
                      await _recoverKeycodeController.recuperarCodeclave(
                          _emailTextEditingController.text, context);
                      isLoading = false;
                    }
                  },
```

ok we have the following block that navigates to the next screen to enter the new password, here it will travel based on the response obtained.

```
class RecoverKeyController {
  final RecoverKeycodeService _recoverKeycodeService = RecoverKeycodeService();
  recuperarCodeclave(String codigoRecuperacion, BuildContext context) async {
    List datos;
    datos = await _recoverKeycodeService.ingresarcodigo(codigoRecuperacion);
    print(datos);
    if (datos[0]) {
      print('proceso exitoso $datos');
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => RecoverNewKeyScreen(idUsuario: datos[1]),
      ));
    } else {
      print('proceso no exitoso $datos');
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "codigo errado por favor intente nuevamente",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0);
    }
  }
}
```

(
the prints to do the debugging were not shown in the console. I do not know why
)
and here is the code in charge of carrying out the process that I am talking about

```
class RecoverKeycodeService with ChangeNotifier {
  RecoverKeyCodeModel _recoverKeyCodeModel = RecoverKeyCodeModel(
    data: Data(
      codigo: '',
      estado: false,
      id: 0,
      idUsuario: '',
      createdAt: '',
      updatedAt: '',
    ),
    msg: '',
    status: 0,
  );
  Future ingresarcodigo(String codigoRecuperacion) async {
    final isConect = await isConnect();
    if (isConect) {
      // final data = {'correo': correo};
      // print(data);
      //'${Environment.urlApi}/auth/codigoValido/$codigoRecuperacion');
      final url = Uri.parse(
          'https://potapi.espaciocientifico.com/api/auth/validateCode/$codigoRecuperacion');

      final resp = await http.post(url,
          // body: jsonEncode(data),
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

      if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
        Map<String, dynamic> codigoService = jsonDecode(resp.body);

        if (codigoService['status'] == 200) {
          return [true, codigoService['data']['idUsuario']];
        } else {
          return [false, 0];
        }
      } else {
        return [false, 0];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I repeat again. Once I enter the code sent through gmail, which are numerical digits, when I tap the button to do the process, it only shows me the number of taps I do on the button but I don't do the process that I should. thanks a lot